# What exactly does bcdedit do?

Tags: regedit, bcdedit

In windows, to start in safe mode we can execute in the terminal, with privileges, the command:

```
%windir%\system32\bcdedit.exe /set {default} safeboot minimal
```

And to return to normal mode, we execute:

```
%windir%\system32\bcdedit.exe /deletevalue {default} safeboot
```

I want to know is what exactly does bcdedit do? (And if I can do the same with registry keys?)

Thanks

---

**Answer to the second part of the question (regedit keys)** ([source](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/560042/force-windows-to-boot-into-safe-mode/))

safe mode:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Option]
"OptionValue"=dword:00000001
```

Normal mode. Delete the previous key or:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Option]
"OptionValue"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: @Ramhound. I will restore the answer. However you are wrong. I just found the solution and tried it and it works. https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/560042/force-windows-to-boot-into-safe-mode/

Comment: It appears that the BCD store is mirrored at `HKLM\BCD00000000`, however, modifying these values will not necessarily modify the actual BCD store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, it modifies the Boot Configuration Data which you can read about on the Microsoft Docs site here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdedit-command-line-options

> BCDEdit is a command-line tool for managing Boot Configuration Data (BCD).
>
> BCD files provide a store that is used to describe boot applications and boot application settings.
>
> BCDEdit can be used for a variety of purposes, including creating new stores, modifying existing stores, adding boot menu options, and so on.